# Angular - Event for ng-hide and ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I'd like to watch my hide and show expressions on all elements in my app.

I know I can do it by wrapping the show directive with a function which just returns the argument:

```
<div ng-show="catchShow(myShowExpr == 42)"></div>
```

However, I'd like to watch all hide/shows across all inputs in my app and the above isn't good enough.

I could also overload the `ngShow` / `ngHide` directives though I'd need to reevaluate the expression.

I could also just modify the source since it's quite simple:

```
var ngShowDirective = ['$animator', function($animator) {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    var animate = $animator(scope, attr);
    scope.$watch(attr.ngShow, function ngShowWatchAction(value) {
      var fn = toBoolean(value) ? 'show' : 'hide';
      animate[fn](element);
      //I could add this:
      element.trigger(fn);
    });
  };
}];
```

Though then I couldn't use the Google CDN...

Is there a nicer way anyone can think of to do this ?

Comment: could write your own display directive instead of using `ng-show`

Comment: Can I ask what the business need is here?  I'm trying to think if there's a better way to do this..

Comment: I've got a complex form and when an element is hidden, it needs to be cleared. Currently, I'm doing this in my own slide [animation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/angular.Module). Though if I decide to fade an element, or instantly hide/show, it quickly becomes quite hacky. Hence the need for an event.

Since the `ng-show` directive implementation is reasonably simple, I might just go with @charlietfl's suggestion and implement my own directive.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's what I've come up with (CoffeeScript)

```
getDirective = (isHide) ->
  ['$animator', ($animator) ->
    (scope, element, attr) ->
      animate = $animator(scope, attr)
      last = null
      scope.$watch attr.oaShow, (value) ->
        value = not value if isHide
        action = if value then "show" else "hide"
        if action isnt last
          scope.$emit 'elementVisibility', { element, action }
          animate[action] element
        last = action
  ]

App.directive 'oaShow', getDirective(false)
App.directive 'oaHide', getDirective(true)
```

Converted to JavaScript:

```
var getDirective = function(isHide) {

  return ['$animator', function($animator) {
    //linker function
    return function(scope, element, attr) {

      var animate, last;
      animate = $animator(scope, attr);
      last = null;

      return scope.$watch(attr.oaShow, function(value) {
        var action;
        if (isHide)
          value = !value;

        action = value ? "show" : "hide";

        if (action !== last) {
          scope.$emit('elementVisibility', {
            element: element,
            action: action
          });
          animate[action](element);
        }

        return last = action;
      });
    };
  }];
};

App.directive('oaShow', getDirective(false));
App.directive('oaHide', getDirective(true));
```

Comment: I am OP... Look at the accounts before you post.

Comment: "Coffeescript" tag added to question. Downvote left on answer. :)

Comment: Down-voted for including CoffeeScript in the answer ? Owell. Haters gonna hate.

Comment: Upvoted because seriously, the dude answered his own question and it's a totally valid answer, language holy war aside.

Comment: As a general note, an answer being posted by the question author doesn't inherently make the answer valid, this place is supposed to be a record for other users, so the answer really should match the question. It does now, but y'know, for future reference.

Comment: @gnack Thank you! The downvote was because of the passive-aggressive attitude, so I decided not to forgive the fact that the question was missing any indication that a CoffeeScript answer would be acceptable (which may be useless to many other users). For the record I actually like CoffeeScript, but I suppose there's nothing like the instant gratification of Internet cynicism!

Comment: Same. Upvote to counter the users that degrade this site with their holier than though attitude

Comment: What's `attr.oaShow`?

Comment: Just an example alternative to `ngShow`, you can give the directive any name

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach is to `$watch` the attribute of `ngShow` - although this would need to be done within a directive (useful if you're show/hiding an already custom directive)

```
scope.$watch attrs.ngShow, (shown) ->
  if shown
    # Do something if we're displaying
  else
    # Do something else if we're hiding
```